# What is the problem of incompatibility of library versions and how monorepo-style solve it?

Tags: monorepo, nrwl-nx

I started to interest in monorepo approach and Nx.js in particularly. Almost all articles talks that monorepo solve the problem of incompatibility of library versions and I don't quite understand the how. There I have few questions:

1. If i understood right, the idea of monorepo (in terms of shared code) that all shared code always the same version and all changes are happen in one atomic commit (as advertisement of monorepo states). So lets imagine monorepo with 100 of projects and all of them are depend on `libA` in the same repo. If I change smth in `libA` than I have to check changes in all dependent project. Moreover, I have to wait all codeowners to review my changes. So what is pros?
2. Lets imagine I have monorepo with following projects: `appA`, `libC`, `libD` and there are some third party library, let's call it `third-party-lib`. `appA` depends on `libC` and `libD`. At some time `appA` need `third-party-lib-v3`, BUT `libC` depends on `third-party-lib-v1`. https://monorepo.tools/#code-generation states that: "One version of everything
   No need to worry about incompatibilities because of projects depending on conflicting versions of third party libraries.". But it is not. In world of Javascript it results in 2 different versions of `third-party-lib` in different `node_modules`. Angain what is pros?

I could be very naive in my questions because I never encountered problems with libraries, also I just started learning monorepo topic so I would be glad if someone help me to deal with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having worked with shared code in a non-monorepo environment, I can say that managing internal packages without a monorepo like NX requires discipline and can be more time consuming.

In your example of 100 projects using 1 library, all 100 projects should be tested and deployed with the new version of the code. The difference is **when**.

In separate repos, you would publish the new version of your package, with all the code reviews and unit testing that go along with it. Next you would update the package version in all your 100 apps, probably one by one. You would test them, get code reviews, and then deploy them.

Now, what if you found an issue with your new changes in one of the apps? Would you roll back to the previous version? If it was in the app then you could fix it in that one app, but if it was in the library, would you roll back the version number in all your apps? What if another change was needed in your library?

You could find yourself in a situation where your apps are using different versions of your library, and you can't push out new versions because you can't get some of your apps working with the previous version. Multiply that across many shared libraries and you have an administrative nightmare.

In a mono-repo, the pain is the same, but it requires less administrative work. With NX, you know what apps your change is affecting and can test all those apps before you deploy your changes, and deploy them all at once. You don't block other changes going into your library because the changes aren't committed until they are tested everywhere they are used.

It is the same with third party libraries. When you update the version of a library, you test it in all applications that use it before your change is committed. If it doesn't work in one application, you have a choice.

- Fix the issue preventing that application from working OR
- Don't update the package to the new version

It means that you don't have applications that are 'left behind' and are forced to keep everything up to date. It does mean that sometimes updates can take so much time that they are difficult to prioritise, but that is the same for multi-repo development.

Finally, I would to add that when starting to work with NX you may find yourself creating large, frequently changing libraries that are used by all apps, or perhaps putting large amounts of code in the apps themselves. This leads to pain where changes frequently result in deployments of the whole monorepo. I have found that it is better to create app specific folders that contain libraries that are only used by that app, and only create shared libraries when it makes business sense to do so. Examples are:

- Services that call APIs and return business domain objects that should not really be changed (changes to these APIs and responses generally result in a V2 of the API and a new NX library could be created to serve that V2 API, leaving the V1 unchanged).
- Core, stable atomic UI libraries for each component (again, try not to change the component itself, but create a V2 if it needs to change)

More information on this can be found here [NX applications and libraries](https://nx.dev/more-concepts/applications-and-libraries)

Comment: Stuart, thank you for detailed response. I still have few quetsions:
1. About libraries. I thought that in monorepo u don't even have versions for libraries which are parts of mono-repo, it's just like separate folder which I can use to import stuff from, right? As I understand that I nor just have more control over affected apps(which is great) also I don't need to suffer with versioning/publishing. Is it right?
2. Is it ok to add questions to thread after sometime?) I just liked a lot your explanation
P.s. I don't know hot to tag someone((

Comment: Yes, a library doesn't really have a version, but you can just create a new library as a new version of the old library. This is only necessary for breaking changes in highly referenced libraries. You could call it V2 or something, although I haven't really got good advice for naming, other than don't use 'new' or 'old'. It is similar to a REST API [URI versioning](https://restfulapi.net/versioning/). Just be careful regarding the differences between folders and libraries. The NX dependency graph works in libraries, not folders or modules.